# Is this sequence that hard?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

I published a sequence that seems difficult to the general public, so I've thought of posting it here. It has a very simple logic (language independent). Can you figure out the next number?

[image]

Comment: Would I sound pedantic if I said that there is a polynomial solution to any finite number sequence? And that there are always an infinite number of solutions anyways?

Comment: I think the polynomial interpolation for these 9 numbers can be fairly complex compared to the intended solution.

Comment: @fffred I'm surprised Mathematica doesn't have a "generate number sequence puzzle solution" built-in, then we could really annoy people who ask these.

Comment: @OrangeDog, It would not be so difficult to make anyway, but I tend to agree that these puzzles are often not the most interesting.

Comment: @fffred. Totally agree, there are infinite solutions to this. I get particularly irked when these problems are framed such that you're a 'genius' if you can figure it out (not the case here, but it is inferred a wee bit). I cant find it in web searches, but I remember reading about Feynman or maybe Neumann (very different personalities!) who kept interrupting someones speech with solutions when they posed a similar 'problem' (with a singular solution expected :).

Comment: @OrangeDog, As far as I was aware Mathematica connects to Wolfram Alpha (?), which I assume would have awareness of the  [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) ?

Comment: @fffred The fact that someone on a forum posts that "there is a polynomial solution to any finite number sequence" shows just how far removed this particular forum is from "the general public".

Comment: @LamarLatrell OEIS wouldn't provide the infinite solutions that exist, but does have the one OP had in mind: https://oeis.org/A090928

Comment: @wedstrom Thats's true. It seems the site's mission to attract 'experts' may be getting somewhere.

Comment: @wedstrom @A E, indeed, it really says something about "the general public"s ignorance.

Comment: @LamarLatrell: It's the other way around, Wolfram Alpha uses Mathematica as its internal engine. Mathematica doesn't connect to the internet by default for most calculations, but you can have it do that. Also, I think OrangeDog just meant a quick way to find a polynomial extrapolation.

Comment: @fffred (and others): It is somewhat pedantic, because while there are infinitely many continuations, they have different Kolmogorov complexities. So it's definitely a legitimate puzzle "find the simplest sequence which this is the start of". (Of course, it's not always the case that the simplest solution is the one a questioner had in mind).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Probably way over thinking this:

> 18

There is a hint that:

> The background of the image is the Milky Way Galaxy, a spiral galaxy.

Reason:

> Start by writing the natural numbers out in a spiral, as follows:
>
> ```
>   25 10→11→12→13
>    ↑  ↑        ↓
>   24  9  2→ 3 14
>    ↑  ↑  ↑  ↓  ↓
>   23  8  1  4 15
>    ↑  ↑     ↓  ↓
>   22  7 ←6 ←5 16
>    ↑           ↓
>   21←20←19←18←17
> ```
>
> Now flip the numbers vertically:
>
> ```
>   21 20→19→18→17
>    ↑  ↑        ↓
>   22  7  6→ 5 16
>    ↑  ↑  ↑  ↓  ↓
>   23  8  1  4 15
>    ↑  ↑     ↓  ↓
>   24  9 ←2 ←3 14
>    ↑           ↓
>   25←10←11←12←13
> ```
>
> And horizontally:
>
> ```
>   17 18→19→20→21
>    ↑  ↑        ↓
>   16  5  6→ 7 22
>    ↑  ↑  ↑  ↓  ↓
>   15  4  1  8 23
>    ↑  ↑     ↓  ↓
>   14  3 ←2 ←9 24
>    ↑           ↓
>   13←12←11←10←25
> ```
>
> Now simply follow the spiral and read them out.

Comment: What! I chosed the Milky Way image randomly! And, yes, it turns out it is a hint!

Comment: How do you even think about this so quickly :o ?

Comment: @EdgarG. Ha, that was the key thing that made me think I was on the right track.

Comment: Uh... This is "a very simple logic"?  :P

Comment: Rather than doing all the flipping - Just create the spiral and then follow a spiral rotated by 180.

Comment: Even though the OP didn't mean for the background image to be a hint, your attention to detail remains very impressive.

Comment: Ahem, your formatting there... http://postimg.org/gallery/167avmc2q/

Comment: @warspyking it looks good on PC (chrome anyway), but yeah not so much on mobile (similar issues on Android). Pretty sure it's a bug with the spoiler block.

Comment: Yeah.. I can't seem to fix it. I think it's the Pre blocks.

Comment: @KeyboardWielder Well, when I said 'very simple logic' I meant no calculations were needed. I still think the spiral logic is fairly simple, but difficult to discover; that was the point, in fact, this is what I like of puzzles.

Comment: In math terms, you performed some arbitrary operations on a Ulam Spiral... and this is **easy** to guess??

Answer (score 16):

> 0 because it's the only digit not used yet

Comment: arrgh! Beat me by seconds... :-)  I have a feeling that there's more to this though...

Comment: @Ben - 66 seconds is probably too long to be characterized as "seconds". ;)

Comment: Personally, I often regard anything more than 0 seconds  as "merely seconds"  As in "We made love for hours, yet she correctly told me It was 'merely seconds.'"

Answer (score 13):

> 10

Because

> if you place a mirror in the middle of the sequence (between the 9 and the 2), every number and its reflection would add up to 11 (and the "?" is opposite the 1).

Comment: Quite interesting, but then, how would you continue the sequence? (I didn't say it was infinite, though)

Comment: I assumed it was finite when I saw that you didn't deny it when @fffred commented "there's polynomial solution to every finite sequence".

Comment: @AimanAl-Eryani: The "finite sequence" that fffred refers to is the nine elements supplied in the puzzle: 1,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,5. The point (s)he was making is that there's always a polynomial *p* such that *p(i)* is the *i*th element of the sequence, and since a polynomial is defined for *all* real numbers, you can always use the polynomial to trivial extend the sequence to an infinite one. (In fact, there are infinitely many such polynomials, though only one of minimal degree.)

Comment: If you inspect the _16_ numbers following those given in the puzzle, and then the _24_ numbers after that, you'll see similar. :)

Answer (score 7):

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/A090928) says

> 18
>
>  (Beginning of sequence A090928: "Permutation of natural numbers arising from a spiral.")

It includes a comment which is much the same as the reason given by p.s.w.g., but

> doesn't flip. It just reads out counterclockwise after writing clockwise:
>
> ```
>  17.16.15.14.13
>  18..5..4..3.12
>  19..6..1..2.11
>  20..7..8..9.10
>  21.22.23.24.25
> ```

(Actually, that's one of 2 sequences in OEIS.  There's also one where the nine digits appear thirty some positions into the sequence.  Wouldn't make a good puzzle.)

Comment: (1) I don't know what "OEIS" is; please spell it out and provide a link.  (2) Answers on Stack Exchange should be self-sufficient and free-standing.  Even in conjunction with p.s.w.g.'s answer, I don't understand this answer.  Please explain the logic. (3) Use spoiler markdown, not code block.

Comment: @PeregrineRook: [OEIS](http://oeis.org) is the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer is:

> 10

And my reason is better than Aiman Al-Eryani's because there is no arbitrary mirror position.

> 1 , 2,3,4,5 , 6,7,8,9 , 10,11,12,13 , ...
>
> 6,7,8,9 , 10,11,12,13 , ...
>
> (Just take one block at a time alternating between the sequences.)

Comment: This is the best answer, to me. "Simple logic" is to make as little steps as possible, and constructing a spiral is NOT simple.

Comment: @Pimgd: Exactly. You might be interested in reading about Kolmogorov complexity, which is one way to make "as little steps as possible" precise. For example if we fix the Turing-complete language as Javascript, my solution is expressed by the function `f(n){return (n-2>>3<<2)+(n+2)%8+2;}`. I challenge anyone to beat that (in Javascript of course)!

Comment: I came up with 10 for the same reason.    I agree it's the simplest conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Well I got 2.

Series is: 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, x

Start from central pair:

9 - 2 = 7

8 - 3 = 5

7 - 4 = 3

6 - 5 = 1

therefore, 1 - x = -1

=> x = 2

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> 0
> Because it's the only digit not represented yet...

Answer (score 2):

It is

> 10

Because

> it starts out 1, leaps out by 5, then does a sequence of 4 numbers, then jumps down by 7, repeat. Adding 5 to 5 yields 10.

Answer (score 2):

> 14

Solution:

> Take the natural numbers and always swap tuples with a length of 4. Starting from
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, ...
>
> the resulting sequence is
>
> 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 10, 11, 12, 13, 22, ...